# Asp.net hashing (using codesmith) when upgrading from .net 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, framework

I'm administrating servers running IIS 6, hosting a website on ASP.NET 2.0.
Yesterday I installed .Net framework 3.5, and all my user authentication system was lost.
Users can't log in, because their password arn't getting authenticated, maybe because the hash function has changed in 3.5???
I can't really get to the code, but I know it uses an extention called CodeSmith.

Do you know of any break my upgrade the 3.5 ugrade could couse?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243813/asp-net-hashing-using-codesmith-when-upgrading-from-net-2-0-to-3-5

Sounds like a similar problem, do you have a backup which you can compare the machinekey with from before the upgrade?